# Covariance of ratio of dependent variables?

Tags: random-variable, covariance, delta-method

I am trying to use the Delta method ([Please have a look at this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539426/derivation-covariance-between-ratio-of-random-variables)) to compute the covariances between the ratios of random dependent variables.
I have 7 **dependent** variables $A_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.
The $A_i $ variables are strictly positive.
I have experimental estimates of the expected values, and the variance covariance matrix of the $A_i$ variables, that is I have estimates of $cov(A_i,A_j) \forall\{i,j\}$.

($A_1$ and $A_7$) are identically distributed.  ($A_2$ and $A_6$) are identically distributed. ($A_3$ and $A_5$) are identically distributed.

Let $A_T=\sum_iA_i$ and $A_t^j=A_t-A_j$

I want to compute estimates of the covariances between the normalized $A_i$ as a function of the estimates I already have. That is I want to compute

$$cov(\frac{A_i}{A_T},\frac{A_j}{A_T})$$

I want to use the Delta method as in the post above, so I define :

$g(A_i,A_j,A_T)=\left(g_1,g_2\right)=\left(\frac{A_i}{A_T},\frac{A_j}{A_T}\right)$
and try to write $ \nabla g$ mimicking the link above. 
The first term for example is given by $\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial A_i}=\frac{1\times A_T-\partial A_T/\partial A_i\times A_i }{A_T^2}=\frac{A_T-A_i}{A_T^2}=\frac{A_i^T}{A_T^2}$ where I have assumed de facto that $\partial A_j/\partial A_i =0 $ for $j\neq i$ which **feels** wrong as they are dependent variables.

Can you confirm or refute the validity of this derivation ? Can you give me a method to compute the covariance of normalized variables ? Even approximatively

Comment: It's impossible to obtain an answer because "dependent" is too vague.  Can you tell us more specifically about *how* the $A_i$ are dependent?  Much of this question is mathematically mysterious, too.  For instance, in what sense are you differentiating a *random variable* $A_i$ with respect to *another random variable* $A_T$ at the end?  And if you really just mean the algebraic formulas--namely, that $A_T$ is the sum of the $A_i$--then clearly the derivative of $A_T$ w.r.t. $A_i$ equals $1,$ so how could the inverse derivative be zero??

Comment: @whuber, euh the variables are atomic populations, the probability distribution is not known as it is driven by an intractable many body hamiltonian. By dependent, I just meant that they were not independent, in particular they should have non zero covariances in theory. In regards to differentiation, I was mimicking the link in the question, which I don't claim to understand fully, it also mysterious to me, especially since the variables are discrete in my case. Your last point makes sense,.

Comment: @whuber, do you know of a way to find the covariances anyway ? even approximatively ? I was looking up the wikipedia page on taylor expansions for random variables which led me to the Delta method which led me to ask this question... The $A_i$ variables are not anything describable by me in mathematicalterms, unfortunately

Comment: Since you don't know the distribution of the $A_i,$ you're going to have to make estimates.  *Why not directly estimate the covariances of the normalized $A_i$?*

Comment: If you mean experimentally, all I have access to is the expected values, variances, and covariances of the $A_i$ variables, it is hard to explain but, basically experimentally I can deduce these expected values, variances, and covariances but I cannot have access to a sample of the $A_i$ variables. That is why I was trying to find  a way to express the mixed moments of the normalized variables as a function of the mixed moments of the non normalized variables . Not sure if I am clear

Comment: Well, at least having estimates of the covariances is more than you have stated in the question! Because a key consideration in applying the delta method is that $A_T$ stays away from $0,$ the meaning of your notation "$[|1;;7|]$" is important: please explain.

Comment: BTW, would these variables be *exchangeable*?  That means they can be correlated but swapping any two of them produces the same multivariate distribution.  That would be a nice simplification.

Comment: @whuber they are not exchangeable, only some of them are identically distibuted (see edit of the question). I have edited my question according to your comments.